# Enhance Ansible Jinja2 to improve performance for for loop with if statement

Tags: loops, ansible, jinja2

let me share my code first before explaining what I wish to perform

this is my vars.yml

```
variable1:
  - { nameField1: "valueField1A", nameField2: "valueField2A", nameField3: "valueField3A"  }
  - { nameField1: "valueField1A", nameField2: "valueField2B", nameField3: "valueField3B"  }
  - { nameField1: "valueField1B", nameField2: "valueField2C", nameField3: "" }
  - { nameField1: "valueField1C", nameField2: "valueField2D", nameField3: "valueField3C" }

variable2:
  - { nameField1: "valueField1A", nameField2: "valueField2A", nameField3: "valueField3A" }
  - { nameField1: "valueField1A", nameField2: "valueField2A", nameField3: "valueField3B" }
  - { nameField1: "valueField1B", nameField2: "valueField2C", nameField3: "valueField3C" }
  - { nameField1: "valueField1B", nameField2: "valueField2C", nameField3: "valueField3D" }
```

this my main.yml

```
- template:
    src: "source_destination/template.j2"
    dest: "target_destination/{{item.nameField3}}.xml"
  loop: "{{variable2}}"
```

this my template.j2

```
{% for myitem in  variable1 %}
{% if item.nameField2 == myitem.nameField2 and myitem.nameField3|length > 0  %}
<header>{{ myitem.nameField3 }}</header>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Can I know is there a better way to perform the for loop as this will cause it loop several times for variabl1 just to check 1 value and get the respective value. I feel this is time consuming. Any other suggestions from the ground?

Update

I believe we can do something like this using selectattr. However, since mine using old jinja2 and i not allow to upgrade this method cant work.

```
{% for myitem in  variable1 | selectattr('nameField2', 'equalto' , item.nameField2) | list %}
{% if myitem.nameField3|length > 0  %}
<header>{{ myitem.nameField3 }}</header>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want it to work with jinja2 itself. what i want is, the variable list of dictionary should filter first in jinja2 itself, then we can loop . in this case for each variable2 it will loop once rather than looping 4 time as in variable1

Answer (score 0):

Your example data is a bit hard to understand and you question lacks a bit of description grounding this to a real life use case. So I'm not entirely sure the below is fulfilling your requirement. But if I'm not to far from it, it will hopefully put you on track. You actually don't even need a template IMO. In a nutshell:

The playbook `test.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: "Filtering lists..."
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Your original values on single lines for legibility
    variable1: [{"nameField1":"valueField1A","nameField2":"valueField2A","nameField3":"valueField3A"},{"nameField1":"valueField1A","nameField2":"valueField2B","nameField3":"valueField3B"},{"nameField1":"valueField1B","nameField2":"valueField2C","nameField3":""},{"nameField1":"valueField1C","nameField2":"valueField2D","nameField3":"valueField3C"}]
    variable2: [{"nameField1":"valueField1A","nameField2":"valueField2A","nameField3":"valueField3A"},{"nameField1":"valueField1A","nameField2":"valueField2A","nameField3":"valueField3B"},{"nameField1":"valueField1B","nameField2":"valueField2C","nameField3":"valueField3C"},{"nameField1":"valueField1B","nameField2":"valueField2C","nameField3":"valueField3D"}]

    # List of all nameField2 values in variable 2
    list_names2: "{{ variable2 | map(attribute='nameField2') }}"

    # This will contain all entries in variable1 where nameField3
    # has an actual value (or evaluates to false, so tune this if needed)
    # and where nameField2 exists in variable2
    valid_1: "{{ variable1 | selectattr('nameField3') | selectattr('nameField2', 'in', list_names2) }}"


  tasks:
    - name: illustrate result with debug
      debug:
        msg:
          - "I would write the following line inside {{ file }}"
          - "<header>{{ header }}</header>"
      vars:
        header: "{{ item.nameField3 }}"
        # Note: I have no idea from your example data
        # if you really want to get the filename from varialbe 2
        # or if both `nameField3` will always be equal.
        # In this last case you can replace all the jinja2 part
        # below with the same value as above
        file: "target_destination/{{ variable2 | selectattr('nameField2', '==', item.nameField2) | map(attribute='nameField3') | first }}.xml"
      loop: "{{ valid_1 }}"

    - name: Corresponding copy task as an example
      copy:
        content: "<header>{{ header }}</header>"
        dest: "{{ file }}"
      vars:
        header: "{{ item.nameField3 }}"
        file: "target_destination/{{ variable2 | selectattr('nameField2', '==', item.nameField2) | map(attribute='nameField3') | first }}.xml"
      loop: "{{ valid_1 }}"
      when: false  # Remove this to actually play
```

which give:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [Filtering lists...] ***************************************************

TASK [illustrate result with debug] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'nameField1': 'valueField1A', 'nameField2': 'valueField2A', 'nameField3': 'valueField3A'}) => {
    "msg": [
        "I would write the following line inside target_destination/valueField3A.xml",
        "<header>valueField3A</header>"
    ]
}

TASK [Corresponding copy task as an example] ********************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'nameField1': 'valueField1A', 'nameField2': 'valueField2A', 'nameField3': 'valueField3A'}) 

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: hi, i need use jinja2 template as <header>{{ header }}</header>. this sample of code. there are more code inside jinja2 template

Comment: ??? The example I gave you uses this exact string. You put it inside a debug, a content to copy to a file (for which I also gave you an example, did you try it ?), or inside a template, the result will be the same. The real thing I changed here is simplify your loop in a loop to only loop once (which removes the need for a template if you only have that single line in your file). If this is not what you want, edit your question an be more specific (with possibly a better and more understandable sample data).

Comment: let me know ya if u understand. what i meant. i got give some example. i cant test it since i using old jinja2. is there something similar can be done using jinja2

Comment: No sorry I don't understand any better. Someone might do better than me. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. besides selectattr('nameField2', '==', item.nameField2), is there any other approach?

Comment: Do you really mean that your current jinja2 version is lower than 2.7? This filter was introduced. If this is really the case, I only see 2 solutions: 1) upgrade 2) if someone is blocking you to upgrade, try to convince him, if he does not want to listen get him out of your way and then upgrade. Jinja 2.7 was released on the 20th May 2013. It's just totally insane to continue using it.

Comment: thank you. i will try convince them